# vertical drop-down navigation with ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I need to create a vertical drop-down navigation menu, and I try with this code but it does not work

home.scss

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #5f3;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
home.html


<button ion-button block icon-right> Palmarés
   <ion-icon   name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon> 
</button>

<ul>
  <button ion-button>
              1
              <ion-icon   name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon> 
        </button>

</ul>

<button ion-button block (click)="nextpage();" icon-right> Classement 
  <ion-icon  name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the popover component from Ionic

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#popovers

It may be what you need.